Reorder Matrix entries programmatically
I have a few hundred entries with a Matrix field that contains blocks with a field I would like to use to order them.
Currently, my blocks are out of order. For example, it might be something like:
- nine
- five
- six
- four
- one

I would like to reorder them:
- one
- four
- five
- six
- nine

The Craft docs seem to say if I supply the following JSON, I can order the blocks:
{
  "sortOrder": [
    321,
    654,
    "new:1"
  ],
}

So presumably if I reorder the IDs of my Matrix entries based on the desired order (one to ten) and resave the Matrix field, that should work. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could do the reordering? It feels like Laravel Collections might be good here but I'm not entirely sure how to approach it.
This is on Craft 5.
